# Django defining __unicode__ on many-to-many linking table

Tags: python, django

Within the Django admin when deleting an object that has a many-to-many relationship I does not show a name despite the two joining tables having `__unicode__` methods.

ie. it just shows... `(user-company relationship: User_company object)`

I was wondering how people go about defined `__unicode__` method on a linking table when it does not exists as a Model in Django? Or is there something else I am missing on the two related tables what would show the related objects name?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its possible by using through keyword to ManyToManyField.
ref 1: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through
ref 2: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Answer (score 3):

You can use `through` parameter of `ManyToManyField` but then you will lost convenient editing of M2M field in the admin.

As alternative you can monkey patch implicit M2M `through` model:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class User(models.Model):
    companies = models.ManyToManyField(Company)

User.companies.through.__unicode__ = lambda x: x.company.name
```

Comment: Excelent. Simple and objective! tx